# Unable to upload files/images to cloud storage (GCP) with Django

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage, python-django-storages

I am trying to upload files & images to the GCP bucket which I created a while ago. I am using Django rest-framework as the backend. I came across this library called `[django storages][1]`. I did everything stated in the library documentation.

1. Create a service account, provided permission as `storage admin` and generated the `json` key.
2. In my projects `settings.py` file I have declared these attributes -

`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"`

`GS_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get("GS_BUCKET_NAME")`

`GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("ibdax.json")`

`GS_PROJECT_ID="project-id"`

Additionally, my models look exactly the same as said in the documentation.

But I still get this error -

```
{
    "error": "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffffa84881d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))"
}
```

These are the logs -

```
Internal Server Error: /api/properties/create-property/
ibdax               | Traceback (most recent call last):
ibdax               |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 482, in thread_handler
ibdax               |     raise exc_info[1]
ibdax               |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 38, in inner
ibdax               |     response = await get_response(request)
ibdax               |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 138, in __acall__
ibdax               |     )(request, response)
ibdax               |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 444, in __call__
ibdax               |     ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
ibdax               |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 414, in wait_for
ibdax               |     return await fut
ibdax               | concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
ibdax               | Application instance <Task pending coro=<StaticFilesWrapper.__call__() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py:44> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/futures.py:351, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0xffff8afea050>()]>> for connection <WebRequest at 0xffff8b38d810 method=POST uri=/api/properties/create-property/?property_files[O]&property_images[O]image: clientproto=HTTP/1.1> took too long to shut down and was killed.
```

After a long time API return this error response. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: Your software cannot connect to **oauth2.googleapis.com**. Your question needs details such as which service you are running your code on, network configuration, firewall rules, etc.

Comment: @Jeet Patel, As mentioned in the previous comment. Can you please provide more details?